# Getting switch statement error when assigning enum type value to property

Tags: swift

I'm trying to assign an enum value type to a structure property using a switch statement. I believe I have the syntax appropriately written (with a ":" after each case statement), however, I'm still getting an error on the "default:" statement. The error reads:
"Expected ':' after 'case'"
Does anyone know what's causing this?

I'm not sure what else to try.

```
struct Town {

    enum Size {
        case small
        case medium
        case large
        case unknown
    }

    // structure properties
    let region = "South"
    var population: Int = 5_422
    var numberOfStoplights: Int = 4
    var name: String?
    lazy var townSize: Size = {
        switch self.population {
        case 0...10000:
            return Size.small
        case 10001...100000:
            return Size.medium
        case let pop where pop >= 100001:
            return Size.large
        case default:    //***********ERROR: Expected ':' after 'case'
            return Size.unknown
        }
    }()
}
```

Expected results: no error
Actual results: error (even though the ":" exists)

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `case` keyword before `default` keyword. That is how `switch` statements work in `Swift`.

Just remove `case` before `default` to solve your problem.

---

Following code snippet is **NOT valid**:

```
switch number {
case 1:
    break
case default:
    break
}
```

**Valid** code:

```
switch number {
case 1:
    break
default:
    break
}
```

Notice how there is no `case` keyword before `default`.

---

To learn more about how `switch` statements work in `Swift` read [official documentation](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID127).

Answer (score 0):

You’re not checking anything, you just need to handle when none case satisfies. For this purpose just use `default` keyword.

```
default:
   return .unknown
```